# JavaScript Discord Bot Level System through Discord-XP

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I do command !leaderboard I'll get an error. I have this code for the leaderboard.js file:

```
const Levels = require('discord-xp');
module.exports = {
    name: 'leaderboard',
    description: 'Leaderboard Command :)',
    async execute(message, args, client){
        const rawLeaderboard = await Levels.fetchLeaderboard(message.guild.id, 5); // We grab top 10 users with most xp in the current server.

        if (rawLeaderboard.length < 1) return reply("Nikdo není v žebříčku.");

        const leaderboard = await Levels.computeLeaderboard(client, rawLeaderboard); // We process the leaderboard.

        const lb = leaderboard.map(e => `${e.position}. ${e.username}#${e.discriminator}\nLevel: ${e.level}\nXP: ${e.xp.toLocaleString()}`); // We map the outputs.

        message.channel.send(`**Leaderboard**:\n\n${lb.join("\n\n")}`);
     
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\xb06\Desktop\Sanoy\node_modules\discord-xp\index.js:262
    if (!client) throw new TypeError("A client was not provided.");
                       ^

TypeError: A client was not provided.
    at Function.computeLeaderboard (C:\Users\xb06\Desktop\Sanoy\node_modules\discord-xp\index.js:262:24)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\xb06\Desktop\Sanoy\commands\leaderboard.js:10:42)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I've tried everything I could, searched on web, and so long, but I can'ť resolve the error.

I am new to JavaScript so idk what to do now.

Comment: You need to somehow pass in a client to the `discord-xp` library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the source code of that `discord-xp` library, and it seems that your client is a falsy value (most likely undefined). Make sure your function is being executed properly

```js
command.execute(message, args, client)
```

With *all* 3 of those arguments, in that order

Comment: Bro once more, tysm this was the mistake, ur awesome :))

Comment: @baartys you can accept this answer if it helped, and answered your question properly